# Disable the Close Button on a Program Running over RDP

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

We have a program that we need to run from a remote Windows 2008 server through RDP as a RemoteApp.  In order to close it properly we need to go to the menu option and choose "Exit".  If we close it with the "X" button in the upper right hand corner it keeps the connection to the database open and causes problems.  We have a policy that tells people to close it the proper way but everyone forgets.

Is there any way I can disable the "X" button on this software or any RDP session window for that matter at the local level?

I am the local admin but have no control over the remote server or how the devs code their buggy software.  All our workstations are running Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: Are they RDP'ing into a desktop and then running the program, or is the program being delivered as a RemoteApp?

Comment: It's a RemoteApp.  I'll update the post.

Comment: I don't think what you ask is possible with RemoteApp. As a workaround you could ask the admin of the server to configure group policy on the server to automatically log off disconnected remote app sessions after a few minutes. Not exactly what you want but it should solve the problem of the remote app being left run indefinitely.

Comment: The application uses a Pervasive DB and when its not closed properly Pervasive thinks the connection is still live even though the application is closed.  When the application is re-started there is a conflict.  The bottom line is its a bug in the software but fixing that is outside my sphere of influence and control.  I'm looking for anyway to prevent our users from closing the RDP Remote app with the "X" button.

Comment: @matt I understand what you're asking, but I don't think there's a way to disable the X button for a RemoteApp session, so you may be forced to use a workaround such as this.  The automatic log off of disconnected sessions very likely would result in the application being closed properly and have the same result as the user closing the RemoteApp properly.